# Как вставлять картинки

Tags: html

Как выбрать и вставить картинку из особых [листов](http://s.ytimg.com/yt/imgbin/www-refresh-vflMLqC23.png), где картинок много. 
И что это вообще за листы?

Comment: Главное не забыть указать размер области (width: height:) куда будет ставится картинка. А вообще такой фишкой многие пользуются.

Comment: Плюс ко всему написанному выше. Технология именуется как - [sprites][1], старо как мир.


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_(computer_graphics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

позиционируют как бэкграунд:

```
background-image: url("http://s.ytimg.com/yt/imgbin/www-refresh-vflMLqC23.png");
background-position: -25px -48px;
```

а делается это для того, чтобы не грузить >9000 картинок при загрузке страницы, а только одну

Comment: Добавлю, что спрайты используются для снижения нагрузки на сервер. Особенно важно для высокозагруженных систем.